# Converting Morse Code to English Text with Java

Tags: java, string

I recently had an assignment to convert English to Morse code and Morse Code to English. When inputting Morse Code, my teacher wants individual letters separated with 1 space, and words separated by a '|'. For example, - --- | -... . is "to be." I was able to get the English to Morse working perfectly, but I am at a loss for Morse to English. I don't know how to get the for loop to stop at the right point and match it up with one of the codes in the array.

Just a side note, my teacher doesn't like Scanner, so he uses his own system of inputs. I'm familiar with his methods, so avoiding Scanner would be appreciated

```
public class Project1
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
        String morse[] = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..",
            "--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",
            "|",".---","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----"};    
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 1234567890";

        String inputType = new String();
        inputType = Input.getString( "Is your phrase in Morse Code or English? Enter 'morse' for Morse Code and 'english' for English" );


        if( inputType.equalsIgnoreCase("morse") )
            morseToEnglish(alphabet, morse);
        else if( inputType.equalsIgnoreCase("english") )
            englishToMorse(alphabet, morse);
        else    
            System.out.println("Your entry is invalid");

    }

    public static void englishToMorse(String alphabet, String morse[])
    {
        String phrase = Input.getString("Enter your english phrase.");
        phrase = phrase.toUpperCase();

        for( int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++ )
        {
            if( phrase.charAt(i) == ' ' )
            {
                System.out.print("| ");
                continue;
            }

            for( int j = 0; j < alphabet.length(); j++ )
            {
                if( alphabet.charAt(j) == phrase.charAt(i) )
                {
                    System.out.print( morse[j] + " " );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void morseToEnglish(String alphabet, String morse[])
    {
        String morseCode = Input.getString("Enter a phrase in morse code.");



        for( int i = 0; i < morseCode.length(); i++ )
        {
            for( int j = 0; j < morse.length; j++ )
            {
                if ( morse[j] == morseCode.charAt(i))
                    System.out.print( alphabet.charAt(j) );

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Oh, sorry if the morseToEnglish code looks incoherent and bad, I've tried many different things and am at a loss.

Comment: Use [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method, first by `|` and then by space.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard I'm not sure it's that he doesn't like it, just that he prefers his own method.

Comment: @PM 77-1 I'm not familiar with the split method, are there any other methods? If not I can look up the split method.

Comment: You could change your loops to while loops and manually increment the index. conditions would be  `i < morseCode.length()` , `charAt (i) != '|'` and `charAt(i) != ' '`.  Append characters to a `String morseletter` inside the inner loop and translate after inner loop.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard he made the students download his own file, called Input.class, and it uses its own syntax as seen in my code. It can receive all primitive data types as well as strings.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard No, a dialogue box pops up that displays a message and a space to input. It's more straight-forward to the students that way

Comment: Would he penalize you for taking some initiative and learning to pop up your own dialog box, or learn streams by playing with System.in/out yourself?  You shoot down a lot of ideas, but really, we're talking about awesome tools.  Things you should know, learn, understand.  Relying on some professors solution for IO isn't going to pay off for you in the long run.

Comment: @gobbly, I realize that, and I know how to use scanner as it is used in the textbook I read. But, for this assignment, I am using his own Input method.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using String.split().  You can split on |, then further split them on spaces.  An enum type with a toString() that prints the character might help compartmentalize the conversion logic (if you don't know switches, this is a good chance to learn them).  Then just concat strings adding spaces as needed.

String.Split() is an amazing tool.  You will benefit greatly by learning it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not familiar with the split method as we have not covered it in my class. Are there any other methods that I could use to achieve the same thing?

Comment: There's always another way to do it.  Early in my CS courses they had us using Tokanizer (think that's the right name), which basically is .split() in an iterative form.  I haven't touched Tokanizer since I learned regex and found split().

You can loop and get substrings, you can parse it all out with charAt()...  remember to use String.equals() if you want to do manual comparisons.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to use the split method and it works perfectly. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The morseToEnglish should just be a reverse of the englishToMorse algorithm.

Like you have before, you can loop through the input strong. The difference is that multiple characters in Morse make a single English character. So keep track of those in a local variable. When you find a space in the Morse, find the English character that matches. You could loop across your Norse array looking for a match, or make a separate mapping where the lookup key is the Morse symbol (something like a HashTable).  And when you get to a pipe character, after finding the character from your local variable, instead of just continuing, you should add an English space to denote the edge of the word before continuing on.