# Morse to English

Tags: java

So the object of the program is in the title. I've managed to successfully convert English to Morse Code but going the opposite way is proving to be difficult. I've looked all over the forums and have not been able to solve my issue here. It seems that it can convert, it just converts the last character of the morse code. I also can't come up with a way to distinguish words from each other using spaces. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/******
* This program will prompt the user to specify the desired type of translation,
* input a string of Morse code characters or English characters, 
* then display the translated results
* 
* Pre-Conditions: 
*
* Post-Conditions: 
*
* @author: PC
******/

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MorseCode
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userInput;

        System.out.println( "This is a Translator." );

        System.out.println( "Would you like to translate sentence to Morse code or English? (MC or E):" );
        String choice = input.nextLine();
        choice = choice.toLowerCase();

        if(choice.equals("e")){
          System.out.println( "Enter sentence (puncuation not needed):" );
          userInput = input.nextLine();
          userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

          String [] morseWords = userInput.split("   ");          

          convertToEnglish(morseWords);
        }

        else if(choice.equals("mc")){
          System.out.println( "Enter sentence (puncuation not needed):" );
          userInput = input.nextLine(); 

          convertToMorse(userInput);
        }
     }

    public static void convertToMorse(String text)
    {
      int i, j;
      String [] morseAns = new String[text.length()];

      text = text.toLowerCase();

      String alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 ");

      String [] morse = new String[] { ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--", 
        "-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",
        ".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----", "|" };

      char selectedChar, convertedChar, alphabetChar;

      for(i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
      {
        selectedChar = text.charAt(i);

        for(j = 0; j < alphabet.length(); j++)
        {
          alphabetChar = alphabet.charAt(j);

          if(selectedChar == alphabetChar) 
          {
            morseAns[i] = morse[j];
          }
        }
      }

     for(i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
     {
       System.out.print(morseAns[i] + " ");
     }

    }

    public static void convertToEnglish(String [] multiMorseWords)
    {
      int i, j;
      String multipleMorseWords;

      String alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 ");

      String [] morse = new String[] { ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--", 
        "-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",
        ".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----", "|" };      

      char [] englishAns = new char[multiMorseWords.length];

      for(i = 0; i < multiMorseWords.length; i++)
      {
        multipleMorseWords = multiMorseWords[i];

        String [] morseChars = multipleMorseWords.split(" ");

        for(j = 0; j < morseChars.length; j++)
        {
          if(morseChars[j].equals(morse[j]))
          {
            englishAns[i] = alphabet.charAt(j);
          }
        }
      }

      for(i = 0; i < multiMorseWords.length; i++)
      {
        System.out.println(englishAns[i]);
      }
    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Morse Code to English Text with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572916/converting-morse-code-to-english-text-with-java)

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please have a look at: [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a map and add all the keys as the morse string and the value as the letter and then iterate over the words and get from map. There is some things you have to handle such as each morse code should be delimited by something, and then word should be different. Like you current have 3 spaces for a word, you would have to delimit the spacing the morse values otherwise I dont see a way to distinguish.

here is an example:

```
public static void convertToEnglish(String[] multiMorseWords) {


        Map<String, String> morse = new HashMap<String, String>();
        morse.put(".-", "a");
        morse.put("-...", "b");
       // etc.. add all the morse code inputs

    for (String word : multiMorseWords) {
        System.out.println(morse.get(word));    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my code! Didn't need to call to split() in the main method, just needed to split in the convertToEnglish method. Here is my revised method:

```
public static void convertToEnglish(String morseSentence)
{
  int i, j;

  String alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 ");

  String [] morse = new String[] { ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--", 
    "-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",
    ".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----", "|" };      

  String [] morseChars = morseSentence.split(" ");
  String selectedMorse;
  char [] englishAns = new char[morseChars.length];

  for(i = 0; i < morseChars.length; i++)
  {
    selectedMorse = morseChars[i];

    for(j = 0; j < morse.length; j++)
    {
      if(selectedMorse.equals(morse[j]))
      {
        englishAns[i] = alphabet.charAt(j);
      }
    }
  }

  for(i = 0; i < englishAns.length; i++)
  {
    System.out.print(englishAns[i]);
  }
}
```